# conditions of an inequation

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I need to find the solutions of this inequation.

[image: \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x^{2}}}{x}<3]

I put the conditions [image: 1-4x^{2}\geq 0] and [image: x\neq 0] then I found x for [image: \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x^{2}}}{x}-3<0]and I obtained [image: x\in (-\infty ,0)]which should be intersected with x from the conditions and I obtain in the final [image: x\in [-\frac{1}{2},0]] but it's not the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the square root you have the condition $$1\geq4x^2$$ this means $$-\frac{1}{2}\le x\le \frac{1}{2}$$ and now you must consider the cases $$x<0$$ or $$x>0$$ Good luck!
Finally you will get $$-\frac{1}{2}\le x\le \frac{1}{2}$$ and $$x\ne 0$$

Comment: Thank you for the response.I got the right answer but I don't understand why I have to consider the cases x<0 and x>0.From that square root I understood that x is in [-1/2,1/2] interval.

Comment: And $$x\ne 0$$ since $x$ is in the denominator.

Comment: I understood, thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice, wish you a nice day!